# node_modules\chromedriver\bin\chromedriver' not found. Is it installed?

Tags: android, node.js, selenium-chromedriver, mocha.js, appium

I am using Chrome apk 83.0.4103 and chrome driver version in node modules is 4.24.2 but still I am facing the below error.

**ERROR webdriver: unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Command '\node_modules\chromedriver\bin\chromedriver' not found. Is it installed?**

When I am running the script my chrome browser is getting launched and is immediately closing

Comment: any one please help me

Comment: Can any one help me in this I badly stuck with this issue

Comment: Its been too long no one is responding. Means no one knows mobile Automation??